# How could I eliminate duplicate headers in Python Camelot when my table spans several pages?

Tags: python, python-camelot

I have a large pdf of tabular data that I'm using Python Camelot to translate into excel sheets. The tables are long enough that they span to the next couple pages, the heading/column names are repeated on each individual page for legibility.

As of now, I am Camelot's Stream flavor and specified columns/table areas to retrieve the information I need, but I notice that every 25 or so rows will have a duplicate header. Is there a way to prevent this in Camelot?

I'm new to Camelot and as far as I know, there isn't a straight forward way to accomplish this without reading the pdf in two separate read_pdf methods. One with a table area including the column names and another without. I'm avoiding this method for the time being as some of the data pdfs I have may have alternate headings in the same spots that are necessary to keep.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.